# ColdFusion 10 and multiple Google Map infowindows

Tags: google-maps, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have read though hundreds of posts to the site - all have been very helpful, but I am stuck where so many others have been - closure issues. My map loads, my markers load, but the infamous infowindow is always displaying the last record's data.

http://harvest.cals.ncsu.edu/applications/kim_test/map/map_test.cfm

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 700px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.8189, -78.6447),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        <cfquery name="alumniMap" datasource="mydatasource" maxrows="10">
        Select MapLatitude, mapLongitude, ID, entity_name
        From tbl_jeffScholarsAlumni
        Order by ID
        </cfquery>

        <cfset p = 1>

        <cfloop query="alumniMap" >
            <cfoutput>
                var #toScript(alumniMap.mapLatitude, "latitude")#;
                var #toScript(alumniMap.mapLongitude, "longitude")#;
                var #toScript(alumniMap.ID, "ncsuID")#;
                var #toScript(alumniMap.entity_name, "ncsupeep")#;
                var #toScript(p, "thisMark")#;          
            </cfoutput> 
            var locations = [
                ['this is me ' + ncsupeep + '...' , latitude, longitude, thisMark],
            ];
            <cfset p = p + 1>

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
            {  
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });
            }

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
                })(marker, i));
            }

        </cfloop>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amend this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

To:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, locations[i][0]);
}
```

Add a new function like so:

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: PS: instead of using the variable `p`, you could use `alumniMap.currentRow` to achieve the same thing

Comment: Good suggestion...if I may be so bold, how would I close an open window when a new window opens?

Comment: I have figured out my last question.

Comment: I assume this is what you did, but I'll add it here anyway.  Simply move `var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();` to above your cfloop